# Bash script store command output into variable

Tags: bash, variables, store

I have a problem concerning storing the output of a command inside a variable within a bash script.
I know in general there are two ways to do this

either

```
foo=$(bar)
# or
foo=`bar`
```

but for the Java version query, this doesn't seem to work.

I did:

```
version=$(java --version)
```

This doesn't store the value inside the var. It even still prints it, which really shouldn't be the case.

I also tried redirecting output to a file but this also fails.

Comment: there are more than two ways.     read foo < <( echo "this is another way")   but this is unrelated to your problem with catching error output, answered below already.

Answer (score 72):

```
 version=$(java -version 2>&1)
```

The version param only takes one dash, and if you redirect stderr, which is, where the message is written to, you'll get the desired result.

As a sidenote, using two dashes is an inofficial standard on Unix like systems, but since Java tries to be almost identical over different platforms, it violates the Unix/Linux-expectations and behaves the same in this regard as on windows, and as I suspect, on Mac OS.

Comment: How do you know if the output is written to stderr or stdout?

Comment: @user1527227: You can test it.

Comment: A bit late but Thank you!!

Answer (score 16):

That is because `java -version` writes to `stderr` and not `stdout`. You should use:

```
version=$(java -version 2>&1)
```

In order to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`.

You can see it by running the following 2 commands:

```
java -version > /dev/null

java -version 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: thank you for your insight, it seems top also prints the version too stderr