# Bash command output not saving to text file or variable

Tags: bash

I am seeing strange behavior when trying to store the output of an SSH check to see if I have SSH access to an account. I tried the following:

```
ssh git@bitbucket.org > temp.txt
```

and I expect a string message telling me if permission was denied or not to be saved to `temp.txt`. But the output goes straight to the terminal and isn't saved to file. But, if I do

```
ls -l > temp.txt
```

that output is saved to file. What could be causing this difference in behavior? I'm ultimately going to be [saving the output to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768228/bash-script-store-command-output-into-variable) but see similar behavior for that case as well. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 bash version 4.3.48(1).

Comment: Since "permission denied" is typically considered an error, is the output being routed to stderr instead of stdout?  If so, you need to use `2> temp.txt` or `> temp.txt 2>&1`.

Comment: @0x5453 I think you're right, that's what I needed to do, and in fact that's in the link I posted I just didn't understand what that syntax meant. Also on a different machine it was working, so it seemed system dependent. Can you write as answer? I'll mark accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since "permission denied" is typically considered an error, is the output being routed to stderr instead of stdout? If so, you need to use `2> temp.txt` or `> temp.txt 2>&1`.

More information:

On many systems, program output is broken up into multiple streams, most commonly `stdout` (standard output) and `stderr` (standard error).  When you use `>`, that only redirects `stdout`, but `2>` can be used to redirect `stderr`.  (This is useful if you want normal output and errors to go to two different files.)

The syntax `2>&1` means "take all output on stderr and redirect it to stdout", so your file would contain output from both streams.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ssh git@bitbucket.org > temp.txt 2>&1
```

Basically what this does it tells linux to redirect stderr (2) to stdout (&1), and then redirect stdout to your file "temp.txt"