# store ls | sort -n | head -1 < this into variable shell script

Tags: linux, shell

so I get the first file in directory by commanding "ls | sort -n | head -1"
is there any way to store this output into a variable shell script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/608639), [Bash script store command output into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9768228/608639), etc.

Answer (score -1):

output of a command can be stored to a variable using backquotes(`). For example.

```
var=`ls | sort -n | head -1`
echo $var
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Even Posix-Shell has `$(....)`, so I suggest using this one instead of the (deprecated and less versatile) backquotes.

Comment: Ya this can be used as well. Both  approaches are correct

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the answer? Why has it been downvoted?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted it. My guess is that it is because of the use of a deprecated features (backquotes) in the answer, because people who will use this answer and maybe pickup the habit of also using this. At least this is the only negative point I can see. Maybe you could bless your backquotes by mentioning, that your solution would even work with csh  ;-)